# Geofire Is not Updating the location in firebase on location change

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation, geofire

I am tryng this code for updating my location in the firebase.. but it is not working as i am changing my location and still it is not updating the location in my firebase database..

```
 String userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Location");
        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(current_user_db);
        geoFire.setLocation(userid,new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()),new
                GeoFire.CompletionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                });


        GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()),0.1);

        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {



            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same problem and then i could solve it by the following method. Click on database in firebase console. Select create Database in Realtime Database. You will recieve a dialog box titled "Security Rules for Realtime Database". In there choose "Start in test mode". This shall solve the problem!!